# Why does writeStream not write in delta format, even though I have coded it

Tags: apache-spark, databricks, spark-structured-streaming, delta-lake

Here is my code. The writeStream is writing records in "parquet" format but not in "delta", even though I have mentioned delta format.

```
spark
.readStream
.format("delta")
.option("latestFirst","true")
.option("ignoreDeletes", "true")
.option("ignoreChanges","true")
.load("/mnt/data-lake/data/bronze/accounts")
.writeStream
.format("delta")
.outputMode("append")
.option("checkpointLocation","/mnt/data-lake/tmp/chkpnt_accounts_inserts")
.option("path","/mnt/data-lake/tmp/accounts_inserts")
.start()
```

Comment: "delta format"? There's no "delta format", but parquet with a transaction log in `_delta_log` directory. If there's this directory, you're likely using a delta format. Can you show the files and directories in `/mnt/data-lake/tmp/accounts_inserts` directory?

Comment: You are right. I mentioned delta as in the format we give "delta". I understand still it's parquet format. However my problem was resolved in the next run and _delta_log directory got created. No clue why it did not happen in the first go!

Comment: Looks like you've sorted it out yourself. If you think there's anything to help you out with, let us know. If not, mind if closed the question (as a user error)?

Comment: Sure..we can close this question. Thanks.

Comment: @DonSam Would you like you post that as an answer so you can mark this question as answered?

Answer (score 0):

Sharing the answer as per the comment by the original poster.

There's no "delta format", but parquet with a transaction log in _delta_log directory. If there's this directory, you're likely using a delta format.

I mentioned delta as in the format we give "delta". I understand still it's parquet format. However my problem was resolved in the next run and _delta_log directory got created.